# Margin 0 auto not centering the ul?

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to center the ul div inside header div.

HTML code:

```
<header>
   <h1>Responsive HTML5</h1>
     <p>This is a demo</p>
    <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></l1>
         <li><a href="Javascript:void(0)">About</a></l1>
         <li><a href="Javascript:void(0)">Services</a></l1>
         <li><a href="Javascript:void(0)">Contact</a></l1>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**CSS CODE**

Here is the css code for the media queries, everything is fine the basic layout but not working with this code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 932px){
        header{position: static; overflow: hidden; background-color: #666;}
        header h1, header p{text-align: center;}
        nav{float:left; position: static; padding: 1px;}
        nav ul{width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;}
}
```

Comment: You are trying to center an element with a width of `100%`. Decrease the width.

Comment: You're having a problem because the text is aligning to the left, no matter what you do.  You need something like text-align.  You can decrease the width like JoshC said, but this won't be as flexible.  Look at this jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/F2Eza/  edit:  http://jsfiddle.net/F2Eza/ for JoshC's sort of solution.  This is less flexible but will allow your bullet points to be in line.

Comment: I pasted the code with wrong width otherwise it was 60%, i have updated it.

Comment: If you remove float: left; from the nav CSS, you'll get it semi-centered.  It'll still be skew because it's centering 60% width instead of your text's width - you can see this illustrated here http://jsfiddle.net/9U7yR/  Setting the width of the nav ul to a more appropriate setting to wrap the text will make it centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav
{
 position: static;
 padding: 1px;
 /* remove float: left; */
}
nav ul
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Will force the TEXT to be centered, but not necessarily the bullet points as well. Setting `list-style-type: none;` will remove the bullet points entirely, making a centered unordered list.

And an FYI, your `</li>` tags should be `</li>`, not `</l1>`

EDIT: Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q826j/14/) for you to look at as well

Comment: Ah ok. If your remove `float: left;` from the `nav` tag, it should recenter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you can do to centralize your UL is to create a CSS for **.nav**

```
.nav
{
margin: 0 auto;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}
```

Also you have a mistake in your HTML code, you have closed **li** tag with **/l1** (it should be **/li**) which is itself an error.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: It isn't .nav, it is nav

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 932px){
    header{position: static; overflow: hidden; background-color: #666;}
    header h1, header p{text-align: center;}
    nav{ margin: 0 auto; list-style-type: none; text-align: center;}
    nav ul{width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; list-style-type:none; }
}
```